# How to forcefully remove wine with unmet dependencies that are not resolved by sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

Firstly, the unmet dependencies are not being met by

sudo apt-get -f install

The following commands were not successful for removing wine

Optional, to remove Wine 1.7.45 and winetricks, open a new Terminal window and bash (get it?) in the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine1.7 winetricks
```

How to Completely removing Wine:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
rm -rf $HOME/.wine
rm -f $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
```

The error that I am receiving after trying to fix the dependcies is as follows

```
imdanerdinator@imdanerdinator-MS-7578:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32z1 wine-compholio-amd64
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  wine-compholio
The following packages will be upgraded:
  wine-compholio
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,222 B of archives.
After this operation, 10.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 263224 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wine-compholio_1.7.45~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wine-compholio (1.7.45~ubuntu14.04.1) over (1.7.29~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wine-compholio_1.7.45~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/wine-compholio/bin/wine64', which is also in package wine-compholio-amd64 1.7.29~ubuntu14.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine-compholio_1.7.45~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I can't figure out how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get remove --purge wine*
# apt-get autoremove
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
# apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Resulted in the same issue and response

Comment: Try: sudo rm -rf /opt/wine-compholio/*